# Ruby interpolation outside of a string

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm running some tests using different user credentials. Each will produce the same error message but I just need to confirm it works.

I've created the following:

```
def login_mrjones
  fill_in('forname', with: 'Steve')
  fill_in('surname', with: 'Jones')
  etc etc
end
```

I've done another for a Mr Davies and some other names.  When writing my step definition, I was looking to use the following, with the variable name being mrjones or mrdavies in the scenario:

```
When(/^I log in as "([^"]*)"$/) do |name|
   login_#{name}
end
```

I was hoping to use interpolation to complete the method to make it generic, this one line would call any login_name methods I have.

Without being a string, the interpolation doesn't seem to work.  Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: I updated my answer. See the comments to the answer as well.

Comment: I would never have a test method that presumed what data is in there or the state of any particular data. Maybe somebody else creates a test that has Steve Jones be a valid active user. Then your test or their test fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do
 `eval("login_#{name}")`

As Stefan and Jörg W Mittag point out you should prefer `public_send` `Klass.public_send("login_#{name}.to_s")`

Or better. Why not add another helper method?

```
def login(name)
  case name
  when 'foo'
    login_foo
  ....
  end
end
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman, thank you.  I need to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer but it will be done!!

Comment: You should use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-send) instead of `eval` for simple method invocation.

Comment: @Stefan: Ideally, prefer `public_send` over `send` as well.

Comment: @Stefan @Tom Well both `eval` and `send` can be avoided by adding another helper method `login`.

Comment: In my opinion, this approach of building a method name to call is not a good idea; instead, I think it better to simply make your login method accept 2 parameters, a first and last name.  Wouldn't that accomplish the same thing, without the added complexity of unnecessary metaprogramming?  It would also eliminate a lot of extra method definitions, and be a more natural expression of Cucumber code.

Comment: My thinking behind this method is that our test data tends to change quite frequently so I'd have one central place to maintain the data instead of going through each feature file to change the parameters.

Comment: @Tom, Just be aware of the caveats with using `eval`

Comment: @Tom - was this a valid answer? If so, you should select it as the answer.... Thanks!